# Swift: ImageView Aspect Fill errors

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to create an UI in a UITableView, t's kind like the Facebook Home Page, on the top, there is a image act like a cover image, on the surface of the this "cover image" there is a "user image".

[Facebook Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP2ll.png)

I did this by adding a `ImageView` first, set the auto layout constrains. and then drag another `ImageView` on top of previous ImageView, and then add the constrains. the "cover image" has a size of 200 * 600(`constrains to the cell with top: 0, left:0, right:0, height: 200`), the "user profile image" has a size of 50 * 50(`constrains to the cell with bottom:0, left:275, right: 275, hight: 50, width: 50`). and the `TableView` I set as static cell with a hight of 300 and width 600

however, when I set the ImageView mode to "Aspect Fill" the "cover image" will fill the whole cell, even though I set it height as 200. and there is no "user profile image" showing.

anybody know is there anything I did wrong? thanks

updated: in my TableView, I have 2 static cell, the first used to put cover image and profile image, the second one is used to put text content. for the second cell, I want it to be dynamic with the text length, so I use this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 300

    }
    return tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

I am not sure if this has anything to do with the problem.

I have tried to only set the cover image first, I add the constrains with(top:0, left:0, right:0, bottom: 100) so the cover image should have a size : 600*200 (the cell is 600* 300). but when I set the image view mode to "aspect fill", it will still fill the whole cell, even thought I set the constrains with bottom: 100.

Comment: Do you see any constraint warnings in the console? If so then fix them and if not showing then, try this: `view.bringSubviewToFront(profileImageView)`

Comment: If you have designed in story board. drag profilpic Image view to that image View. Try with drag and change again. I mean change the hierchy of both in storyboard structure

Comment: where should I add that code? @Santosh

Comment: I tried, when the mode of all image view is "scale to fit", it works as I want( but the image is distorted), but when I change to"aspect fill", the cover image filled the whole cell, and there is no height gap between two image view.@JAck

Comment: Add where you are loading your cover image.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with your constraints. Check the priority level on your height constraint. It should be set to 1000.

If you can't figure it out, another option is to put another view under the cover photo with a size of 100 to act as a spacer then constrain the other images to this spacer view. Then you can put the rest of your elements in this view.

Comment: I have added another view under the cover photo, and removed the profile image view first, when I choose " Aspect Fill" it still fill the whole cell. however, if I change to "Scale to Fill", it works as what I want, the cover image has a height of 200, the view is 300, so there is 100 blank space( I colored it with orange).

Comment: Does this work for you? If so, please accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm struggling to recreate you're issue. I've made a tableview cell as you described and am not getting the same result. Seems to be working fine on my machine. Can you share anything else about your project? Is it on github?

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look. since there is no a lot of code, just few, and I already put on my updated question, thanks.

Comment: check to make sure your bottom constraint is set to = and not <=.

Comment: yes, it is "equal" not "less then or equal". still not working

Comment: did you ever get a break on this one? im facing the same issue